# Issue in cloning projects from private gitlab server

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-8

I have a `gitlab` server, and we are working on projects using our `gitlab`. 
 Recently we have this problem which we can not clone projects from `gitlab` server using either `SSH` or `HTTP` methods. some projects get stuck on 95% some in 11% based on project volume.

what may cause this issue?

Comment: It happens also with --prefer-dist option?

Comment: Maybe cause of low-internet-speed. Try again, better to use in higher-net-speed.

Comment: Your network does not work. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a networking issue, as some commented above. You can try to run 'Housekeeping' on the projects to see if it helps with clone times. For one of the projects with the problem, go to the settings dropdown in the top right, then edit project. Scroll down near the bottom of the page and look for 'Housekeeping'. Wait a minute or two for the process to run, then try the clone again.

If this doesn't fix the problem, look in the GitLab logs while you clone. On an Omnibus installation you can tail all logs with `sudo gitlab-ctl tail`. Watch for any errors.